# How to find character appearence in text

Tags: javascript

How can i find with jquery how many times a character appear in text, for example i have the character **1** and the text **143443143241** so here the character 1 appear 3 times, how can i check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var blah = "143443143241";
var count = (blah.match(/1/g) || []).length; // <-- returns the number of occurrences. 3 in this case.
```

Comment: If `.match()` returns `null`, it will break. You can do `( blah.match(/1/g) || [] ).length` to fix it.

Comment: good idea.  I should probably assign it to a var too just for completeness sake :P

Answer (score 1):

```
"143443143241".match(/1/g).length
```

Edit: What Joseph said 40 seconds before me.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a javascript question, or a generic programming question.

```
function countOccurences(string, testChar) { 
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i<string.length; i++){
        if(string[i] == testChar) { count++; }
    }
    return count;
}

countOccurences("143443143241", "1");
```